# How do I force a Laravel 5.6 redirect from a RedirectResponse object?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I have a custom non-Eloquent class called `Item`. In the constructor, the `Item` attempts to authenticate with my app. I then have an `Auth()` method to check whether the authentication was successful, and if not to fire a redirect.

```
public function Auth() {
    if (isset($this->authenticated)) {
        return $this;
    } else {
        return redirect('/auth');
    }
}
```

I use the `Auth` method to access `Item` statically via a `Item` Facade. The intended outcome is that if the Item is authenticated, we proceed to the Index with that Item as a variable. If not the redirect would be triggered.

```
public function index() {
    $item = Item::Auth();
    return view('index',$item);
}
```

However, if not authenticated, all that happens is a Laravel `RedirectResponse` object is passed to the index view. How can I force that redirect to actually fire?

**Solutions I have thought of but don't like**

`if ($item instanceOf RedirectResponse)...` in the controller, but this feels clunky

`$item = new Item; if ($item->authenticated)...` this is fine for the controller but I want to trigger the redirect from multiple parts of the app so there would be a lot of code re-use which doesn't feel efficient.

Thanks for any help. Either on the Facade front or firing the Redirect object.

Comment: This looks a bit shady. Why not add auth middleware on the `index` route instead?

Comment: I have auth middleware for the user. The `Item` needs to authenticate whenever it is instantiated, which is separate to the routes.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this case by using an `AuthenticationException`:

```
public function Auth() {
    if (isset($this->authenticated)) {
        return $this;
    } 
    throw new AuthenticationException();
}
```

The authentication exception will generate either a redirect to login or a 401 error on JSON routes. You can of course throw a different exception and handle it as a redirect in your `App\Exceptions\Handler` class

For example:

```
public function Auth() {
    if (isset($this->authenticated)) {
        return $this;
    } 
    throw new ItemNotAuthorizedException(); //Custom class you need to create
}
```

In `Handler.php`:

```
 public function render($request, Exception $exception)
 {
    if ($exception instanceof ItemNotAuthorizedException) {
       return redirect("/auth");
    }
    return parent::render($request, $exception);
 }
```

Note: Laravel 5.6 might also allow exceptions to implement their own render function but you should refer to the documentation for that.